# True or False : $P( B \mid A \cup B) \geq P(B \mid A)$

Tags: probability

Trying to prove whether this is T or F and I get stuck..

This is my process so far:

$P( B \mid A \cup B) \geq P(B \mid A)$

$=\frac{P(B\cap(A\cup B))}{P(A \cup B)} \geq \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$

$=\frac{P(B)}{P(A \cup B)}\geq \frac{P(B \cap A)}{P(A)}$

Comment: I read $P(B\mid A\cup B)$ as `probability that $B$ happens given that $A$ and $B$ happen.' So, it should always equal 1, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Given $A$ or $B$... not $A$ and $B$. @atn is correct

Answer (score 3):

More intuitive way per OPs request:

Take the reciprocal of your last inequality:

$$\frac{P(A \cup B)}{P(B)}\leq \frac{P(A)}{P(B \cap A)}$$

Then subtract $1$ both sides"

$$\frac{P(A \cup B)-P(B)}{P(B)}\leq \frac{P(A)-P(B \cap A)}{P(B \cap A)}$$

That can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{P(A \setminus B)}{P(B)}\leq \frac{P(A \setminus B)}{P(B \cap A)}$$

Which is obvious

Comment: That's fairly pretty.

Comment: How does this prove that $P( B \mid A \cup B) \geq P(B \mid A)$? I'm having a hard time visualizing

Comment: Basically since both numerators are the same. I would need to compare the denominators $P(B)$ and $P(B \cap A)$. how can I tell which is larger?

Comment: Note that $B\cap A \subseteq B$, so $P(B\cap A )\le P(B)$.

Comment: Momo - can you please explain how you went from the first equation to the second equation? You are subtracting 1 on both sides? I'm confused on how that second equation is derived from subtracting 1 on both sides.

Comment: On the LHS: $\frac{P(A \cup B)}{P(B)}-1=\frac{P(A \cup B)}{P(B)}-\frac{P(B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(A \cup B)-P(B)}{P(B)}$ and similar on the RHS

Comment: I figured it out. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$
\frac{P(B)}{P(A\cup B)}-\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B)P(A)-P(A\cap B)P(A\cup B)}{P(A\cup B)P(A)},
$$
which is positive, if and only if $P(B)P(A)\geq P(A\cap B)P(A\cup B)$. Now,

$$
P(A\cap B)P(A\cup B)=P(A\cap B)(P(A\setminus B)+P(B\setminus A)+P(A\cap B))\\
\leq P(A\cap B)(P(A\setminus B)+P(B\setminus A)+P(A\cap B))+P(A\setminus B)P(B\setminus A) \\
=P(A)P(B),
$$

if you write out everything.
Thus, the statement is true.

Comment: Is there a more intuitive way of solving this proof? I honestly don't understand this

Comment: $P(A)=P(A\setminus B)+P(A\cap B),$ right?

Comment: And $P(A\cup B)=P(A\setminus B)+P(B\setminus A)+P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: What is P ( A \ B)? Do you mean $P(A \cup B)$?

Comment: $A\setminus B$ is the event "$A$ but not $B$", so $A\setminus B$ and $A\cap B$ are disjoint, and their union is $A$.

Comment: I agree that the above formating is not very readable, but try writing out both products in terms of the above expansion and notice that the only difference is that there is an extra term of $P(A\setminus B)P(B\setminus A)$ on the $P(A)P(B)$ side.

Comment: I think I am getting confused because I have never seen the A \ B event. Is there a way to rewrite that?

Comment: $A\setminus B=A\cap B^{c}$ if that makes you more comfortable (where $B^{c}$ denotes the complement of $B$).

Comment: Ah yes. Let me process it in the light.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this considering 3 cases:

case 1: $B \subset A \implies \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B)}{\mathbb P(A \cup B)} =  \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B)}{\mathbb P(A)} \hspace{11mm} \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B \cap A)}{\mathbb P(A)} = \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B)}{\mathbb P(A)}$

Thus, $\hspace{5 mm} \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B)}{\mathbb P(A \cup B)} = \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B \cap A)}{\mathbb P(A)}$

case 2: $A \subseteq B \implies \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B)}{\mathbb P(A \cup B)} =  \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B)}{\mathbb P(B)} = 1 \hspace{11mm} \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B \cap A)}{\mathbb P(A)} = \cfrac{ \mathbb P(A)}{\mathbb P(A)} =1$

Thus, $\hspace{5 mm} \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B)}{\mathbb P(A \cup B)} = \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B \cap A)}{\mathbb P(A)}$

case 3: $A\cap B = \emptyset \implies  \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B \cap A)}{\mathbb P(A)} = \cfrac{ \mathbb P(\emptyset)}{\mathbb P(A)} = 0 \hspace{11 mm}$ Clearly, $ \hspace{5 mm}\cfrac{ \mathbb P(B)}{\mathbb P(A \cup B)}  \geq 0$

case 4: $A\cap B \not = \emptyset \implies \mathbb P (A) > \mathbb P (A \cap B) \hspace {5 mm} \mathbb P (B) > \mathbb P (A \cap B)$

Therefore, $\mathbb P (B) \cdot \mathbb P (A) - \mathbb P(B \cap A) \cdot \mathbb P(B \cup A) = \mathbb P (B) \cdot \mathbb P (A) - \mathbb P(B \cap A) \cdot (\mathbb P(B) + \mathbb P(A) - \mathbb P (B \cap A)) \\ = \mathbb P (B) \cdot \mathbb P (A) - \mathbb P(B \cap A) \cdot \mathbb P(B) - \mathbb P(B \cap A) \cdot \mathbb P(A) + \mathbb P(B \cap A) \cdot \mathbb P(B \cap A) \\ = (\mathbb P(A) - \mathbb P(B \cap A)) \cdot (\mathbb P(B) - \mathbb P(B \cap A)) > 0$

$\mathbb P (B) \cdot \mathbb P (A) - \mathbb P(B \cap A) \cdot \mathbb P(B \cup A) > 0 \implies \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B)}{\mathbb P(B \cup A)} > \cfrac{ \mathbb P(B \cap A)}{\mathbb P(A)}$

Answer (score 0):

The inequality boils down to showing that $\mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B)\geq \mathbb P(A\cap B)\mathbb P(A\cup B)$. The intuition behind why this is true is the same as the intuition behind the AM-GM inequality: the product of two quantities with given sum decreases as the two quantities become more spread out.

The intuition applies to this problem since $\mathbb P(A\cap B)+\mathbb P(A\cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)$ and $|\mathbb P(A)-\mathbb P(B)|\leq |\mathbb P(A\cup B)-\mathbb P(A\cap B)|$ follows from the more precise identity
$$
|\mathbb P(A\cup B)-\mathbb P(A\cap B)|=|\mathbb P(A)-\mathbb P(B)|+2\min\bigl(\mathbb P(A\setminus B),\mathbb P(B\setminus A)\bigr),
$$
which can be seen for example by drawing a Venn diagram. Consequently
$$
\bigl(\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)\bigr)^2-\bigl(\mathbb P(A)-\mathbb P(B)\bigr)^2\geq\bigl(\mathbb P(A\cap B)+\mathbb P(A\cup B)\bigr)^2-\bigl(\mathbb P(A\cup B)-\mathbb P(A\cap B)\bigr)^2,
$$
which (after expanding squares and cancelling a factor of $4$) yields the desired inequality.